# A question on holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have a domain D (open and connected), and a function f holomorphic on D. If we suppose also that f assumes real values on a certain subset of D, say, a circle within it, what can we conclude about the function f? Would it necessarily be constant? Would it assume only real values throughout D?

In general, what can be said about holomorphic functions assuming real values on certain subsets?

Comment: Just a note: There are plenty of holomorphic functions that are real-valued on the real axis, and we can (at least locally) unbend a lot of curves to subsets of the real axis by holomorphic mappings. In the generality requested a complete answer looks difficult to give.

Comment: I think $f$ must be constant on all $D$ if it is real on any open non-empty set in $D$.

Answer (score 3):

If the subset $X$ you're talking about is a circle, yes, any function $f= u+iv$ which takes real values in it must necessarily be constant.

That's because if the imaginary part $v$ is null in a circle, then it's also null in the ball whose boundary is the circle (because $v$ is a harmonic function). Then, the function $f$ is real in the ball, but that can only happen in the constant case: if $v$ is constantly equal to $0$, then its derivatives are $0$, and so are the derivatives of $u$ (Cauchy-Riemann). One concludes then that $f$ is constant in the ball. By analytic continuation, $f$ must be constant in $D$.

This can be generalized to the case where $X$ is the boundary of an open set (Edit: a *bounded* open set. See peek-a-boo's comment to this same post). In that case, you can deduce that $v$ is null in an open set, because "Dirichlet problem has a unique solución for the boundary condition $v=0$."

Comment: for the final paragraph, you should probably add in the clause that "$X$ is the boundary of a bounded open set" (otherwise, Dirichlet's problem for the Laplacian with $v=0$ boundary condition doesn't have unique solutions. For example in $2$-dimensions, for any $a\in\Bbb{R}$, $v(x,y)=a\cdot \frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)$ is harmonic on the exterior of the unit disc, with boundary value $0$).

Comment: Good remark, thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. Its clear to me now.

Comment: One follow-up question: How would the scenario change if D was not a connected set?

Answer (score 0):

Note that any open continuous map $f$ on a complex domain cannot be real on a Jordan curve $J$  inside the domain (or if $J$ is the boundary and $f$ is continuous on $\bar D$) by general topological considerations, so in particular, that's true for (nonconstant) holomorphic functions, but also for more general ones.

Assume by contradiction there is such an $f$, then $f(J)$ is a compact subset of the reals $A$ so cannot disconnect the plane, but if the interior of $J$ is $U$ open bounded connected, then $f(U)$ is a bounded connected open set in the plane with boundary included in $A$ (as for any open continuous function and any bounded open $U$, one has $\partial f(U) \subset f(\partial U)$ while here $f(\partial U)=f(J)=A$) which is a contradiction with the fact that $A$ doesn't disconnect the plane so $\mathbb C-A \subset f(U)$ unbounded